# Setting size of JOptionPane OptionDialog to fit screen

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class trial
{
    private static final String EXIT_ON_CLOSE = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] option = {
            "Adlawan", "Angeles", "Arreza", "Benenoso", "Bermas", "Brebante","Cabaylo", "C. Cainglet", "O. Cainglet", 
            "Calunsag", "Cameros", "Casanaan", "Catulong", "Chicote", "Dela Paz", "Ea", "Echavez", "Esquivel", 
            "Fudadera", "Gales", "Gentallan", "Gerodias", "A. Guadalupe", "S. Guadalupe",
            "Hanuyan", "Jamero", "Macana","Mangmang","Moncano", "Ocon", "Ortiz", "Oquendo", "Palma", "Paran",           
            "Simbajon", "Torcido", "C. Ylagan", "E. Ylagan",
        };  

        int choose =  JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "                    WHICH EMPLOYEE'S BEGINNING BALANCE WOULD YOU LIKE TO UPDATE?", "Click to Choose Employee",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, option, option[37]);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static void setDefaultCloseOperation(String exitOnClose) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Those are my codes above, the problem i have is that my `JOptionPane OptionDialog` exceeds my screen. My question is, is it possible to change or set a specified size for my `JOptionPane OptionDialog` to make it fit my screen?

I tried using `JScrollPane` and add it to a `JPanel` but i can't make it work.